# Dismiss Completion SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm showing a `fullScreenCover` with SwiftUI. Under certain flows, I want to dismiss the cover and show another from the Root ContentView. When I call

```
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

      Button {
            dismiss()
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.showNewScreen, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
                } label: {
                    Text("This is a test")
                }
```

I get the error:
`[Presentation] Attempt to present xxx from yyy which is already presenting zzz`

UIKit had the helpful completion handler so I could wait until the ViewController was dismissed before adding logic:

```
func dismiss(
    animated flag: Bool,
    completion: (() -> Void)? = nil
)
```

Is there something similar with SwiftUI? My current workaround is to add a delay to avoid presenting on the same view... which feels wrong.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.showNewScreen, object: nil, userInfo: nil)

           }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty to mess with modals in this way, but if you want to present the next modal from the presenting view then you can pass a binding isPresented and use the onDismiss argument for the fullScreenCover view modifier:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: DispatchQueue.main.async { presentNextThingy }) { firstThingyContent }
```

or my preference use a binding that when changed will dismiss and load the next modal view, if needed.  This allows the first view to determine what is presented when it is dismissed by changing the binding directly.

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $thingyBeingPresented) { thingy in 
content(for: Thingy)
}
```